# @types/package node project error how to solve this

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I'm trying to update my all packages which was in my node js project,but if i updating a single package then also having this types of @types/package name error.`

```
`api        |     return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
api        |            ^
api        | TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
api        | src/app.ts(2,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'pg'. '/home/node/app/node_modules/.pnpm/pg@8.11.3/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
api        |   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/pg` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'pg';`
api        | 
api        |     at createTSError (/home/node/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
api        |     at reportTSError (/home/node/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
api        |     at getOutput (/home/node/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
api        |     at Object.compile (/home/node/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
api        |     at Module.m._compile (/home/node/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
api        |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
api        |     at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/node/.npm/_npx/1bf7c3c15bf47d04/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
api        |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
api        |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
api        |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19) {
api        |   diagnosticCodes: [ 7016 ]
api        | }
```

Comment: Have you tried the npm command the error suggests to run?

Comment: @Spikatrix - Yes i had tried but then also having this same error.